# Setting href value from object in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I want to set value from object in href like this

```
<a href="<%result[0].DocumentUrl %>">
```

But i am getting compilation error. Any help in syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an equal sign (`=`):

```
<a href="<%= result[0].DocumentUrl %>">
```

You can read more about the different inline asp tags [here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx).